# Есть 4 функции js. Как их по очереди вызывать каждые 14 дней и далее сначала, но с привязкой к Datetime, а не setInterval

Tags: javascript, html

Нужно именно с привязкой к Datetime, а не setInterval, так как нужно, чтобы функции начали выполняться с определённой даты, и далее чередовались каждые две недели независимо от обновления страницы. К тому же, как я понимаю, ориентироваться на дату пользователя тоже не есть хорошо, но в моём случае не требуется точность до секунды, достаточно чтобы функции выполнялись +-час в определённый день. Или хотя бы куда копать?

```js
let div1 = document.querySelector(".div1");
let div2 = document.querySelector(".div2");
let div3 = document.querySelector(".div3");
let div4 = document.querySelector(".div4");

function function1() {
    div1.style.display = "block";
    div2.style.display = "none";
    div3.style.display = "none";
    div4.style.display = "none";
}

function function2() {
    div1.style.display = "none";
    div2.style.display = "block";
    div3.style.display = "none";
    div4.style.display = "none";
}

function function3() {
    div1.style.display = "none";
    div2.style.display = "none";
    div3.style.display = "block";
    div4.style.display = "none";
}

function function4() {
    div1.style.display = "none";
    div2.style.display = "none";
    div3.style.display = "none";
    div4.style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"> 1 </div>
<div class="div2"> 2 </div>
<div class="div3"> 3 </div>
<div class="div4"> 4 </div>
```

Comment: добудь нужный таймштамп и запиши его в константу. Сделай функцию, которая будет вызывать другие функции по рассчитанной дате (timestamp + 86400000 * 14. 1 день равен 86400000 мс, умножаешь на нужное количество дней). Ну и когда сайт открывается, т.е. вызывается скрипт - тебе нужно, чтобы выполнилась проверка текущего timestamp с нужным, да и всё

Comment: Есть такой "инструмент" https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron или расширения для браузеров поискать

Comment: А что значит каждые 14 дней ? Вот у нас наступил 14 день скажем, вызвалась 1-я функция. Пользователь открывает сайт на 15 день, функция уже вызывалась, значит ни одна из функций не вызывается и пользователь видит все 4 div. И только на 28 день если войдет, то именно в тот день увидит только второй ?

Comment: Начиная с точки отсчёта (например, сегодня) показывается только первый div, далее через 14 дней следующий (первый и остальные скрыты) и так далее, после вызова четвёртой функции цикл повторяется.

Comment: Т. е. пользователи должны всегда видеть только один из четырёх divов, которые будут меняться каждые 2 недели. Далее цикл повторяется сначала.

Comment: А четыре функции то за чем?  Одна функция,  цикл и каждые две недели скрывай нужные три блока открывай нужный...

Comment: Air, сколько функций это не суть, можно и циклом. Мне главное понять как сделать так, чтобы этот двухнедельный цикл работал независимо от обновления страницы пользователем, чтобы цикл начал работать с определённой даты, и далее работал не смотря ни на что. Насколько я понял, это можно сделать на основе Datetime, но куда копать дальше пока не понятно. Как сделать так, чтобы с определённой даты прибавлялось 14 дней и показывался следующий div? Что читать по этой теме или хотя бы по какой логике такие вещи строить?